# Why `cursor: pointer` does not work in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

In FF3 I see a hand when the mouse is over the element, but in IE6 I don't. Why ? Is there any workaround ?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bxUqV/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Philippe mentioned, IE6 only supports `:hover` on `<a>` elements.  You asked for a workaround, the only workarounds require javascript to be enabled:

- [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)
- [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Comment: @resio: thanks for the correction, I didn't have time to test it myself earlier :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set `foo { cursor: pointer; }` (without `:hover`), or (better) use an `a` element as you almost certainly should anyways.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doesn't support ":hover" selectors on anything else than `<a>` elements

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use Javascript if it's anything other than an  tag.  If you're using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('#element').hover( function() {
   $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');  
}, function() {
   $(this).css('cursor', 'inherit');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes `cursor: hand` will work. Best to specify both, for standards-compliant browsers using:

```
cursor: pointer, hand;
```

What you can also do is copy the cursor from a Windows installation and point to it using a URL:

```
cursor: url(pointer.cur);
```

Or, even better yet, have it as a backup and insert it using IE's wacky support for [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```
<!-- normal CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
.clickable {
    cursor: url(pointer.cur);
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```